# The last item you chose in the list is selected in the radio button. How can one item be selected from each row?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

The last item you chose in the list is selected in the radio button. How can one item be selected from each row?

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
@foreach ($products as $product)

    <tr>
        <td scope="row">{{ $i++ }}</td>

        <td>{{ $product->name ?? '' }}</td>
        <td><img src="{{asset($product->image)}}" class="product-img-2" alt="product img"></td>
        <td>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="status" value="active" {{($product->status  == 'active') ? 'checked' : '' }} id="Active">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Active">
                        active
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="status" value="deactive" {{ ($product->status == 'deactive') ? 'checked' : '' }} id="Deactive" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Deactive">
                        deactive
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

        </td>

    </tr>


@endforeach
```

The last one selected is selected. I only want one item from each row to be selected

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a big vague in its meaning; could you edit it and include more info about your problem?

Comment: All of the radio buttons have the same name, so they act as the same input. You'll need to set a different name for each item in the loop. The easiest might be to change the name to an array, and use the product id as the array key. `name="status[{{$product->id}}]"`

Comment: While you're at it, make the `id`s unique too

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple radio button to be selected at the same time, they must have a different `name` attribute.

For example :

```html
<!-- Row 1 -->
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="status-row-1" value="active" id="Active" />
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="status-row-1" value="deactive" />

<!-- Row 2 -->
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="status-row-2" value="active" id="Active" />
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="status-row-2" value="deactive" />
```

Also, here is a tip not related to your question, the `id` attributes should have a unique value, so a different one for all generated inputs.